# Internal Error when creating new user with Firebase Auth in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am working with Firebase for authentication in my application, and below is the function I am calling on my form. Before I had added the .then() with the updateProfile inside, it was working fine. However, now when I create a new user, the user's email and password is stored, but I get the error `Internal error: Too much recursion` and the displayName is never set.

```
const handleSignUp = useCallback(
    async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { fullName, email, password } = event.target.elements;
      try {
        await app
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
          .then((result) => {
            const user = app.auth().currentUser;
            return user.updateProfile({
              displayName: fullName,
            });
          });
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
      history.push("/dashboard");
    },
    [history]
  );
```

I've tried different ways of calling updateProfile (using the function argument & the user variable as in the example below. I am still getting this error.

Is there a way to write this code to avoid that recursion error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest you to choose between using `async/await` or `then` to handle promises.
Second, you can use createUserWithEmailAndPassword return value, as such:

```
const userCredentials = await app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
const user = userCredentials.user;
await user.updateProfile({ displayName: fullName });
```

The relevant documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword